# How to automatically setup SSH key pass on first ansible command run for each new server?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

Today I started learning ansible and first thing I came across while trying to run the command ping on remote server was

```
192.168.1.100 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "(u'192.168.1.100', <paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey object at 0x103c8d250>, <paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey object at 0x103c62f50>)", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

so I manually setup the SSH key, I think I faced this as no writeup or Tutorial by any devops explains the step why they don't need it or if they have manually set it up before the writing a tutorial or a video.

So I think it would be great if we can automate this step too..

Answer (score 0):

If ssh keys haven't been set up you can always prompt for an ssh password

```
-k, --ask-pass      ask for connection password
```

Comment: Well, that isn't my question 

Answer (score 0):

I use these commands for setting up keys on CentOS 6.8 under the root account:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh ${user}@${1} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'mkdir .ssh > /dev/null 2>&1; restorecon -R /root/; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ansible $1 -u $user -i etc/ansible/${hosts} -m raw -a "yum -y install python-simplejson"
ansible $1 -u $user -i etc/ansible/${hosts} -m yum -a "name=libselinux-python state=latest"
```

`${1}` is the first parameter passed to the script and should be the machine name.
I set `${user}` elsewhere, but you could make it a parameter also.

`${hosts}` is my hosts file, and it has a default, but can be overridden with a parameter.

The `restorecon` command is to appease selinux. I just hardcoded it to run against the `/root/` directory, and I can't remember exactly why. If you run this to setup a non-root user, I think that command is nonsense.

I think those installs, `python-simplejson` and `libselinux-python` are needed.

This will spam the `authorized_keys` files with duplicate entries if you run it repeatedly. There are probably better ways, but this is my quick and dirty run once script.

I made some slight variations in the script for CentOS 7 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what types of servers these are, but nearly all Ansible tutorials cover the fact that Ansible uses SSH and you need SSH access to use it.

Depending on how you are provisioning the server in the first place you may be able to inject an ssh key on first boot, but if you are starting with password-only login you can use the `--ask-pass` flag when running Playbooks. You could then have your first play use the [authorized_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) module to set up your key on the server.